# “Badly placed ()'s” error when running loc command

Tags: perl

I keep getting errors like `Badly placed ()'s` and I don't understand why.

The following row is giving me this printout

```
${tmp} = `${loc} ${"${type}_flag"} ${old_view_path}/${old_file} > ${tmpdir}/old_file`;
```

I'm running a command like this

```
system("${ct} startview ${new_view}");
system("${ct} startview ${old_view}");
${new_view_path} = "/view/${new_view}";
${old_view_path} = "/view/${old_view}";
${loc} = "/proj/uz/util/bin/loc";

@{file_types} = ();
${file_type} = "Erlang";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"erl,hrl";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-erl";

${file_type} = "IDL";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"idl";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-erl";

${file_type} = "C";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"c,h";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-c";

${file_type} = "C++";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"cc, cpp, hh, hpp";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-c++";

${file_type} = "Assembler";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"s";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-c";

${file_type} = "Java";
push @{file_types},${file_type};
@{"${file_type}_ext"} = split /,/,"java,classes";
${"${file_type}_flag"} = "-c++";

foreach ${type} (@{file_types}){
     //The bellow give me sometimes error like badly placed ()'s
     ${tmp} = `${loc} ${"${type}_flag"} ${old_view_path}/${old_file} > ${tmpdir}/old_file`;
}
```

It has obviously something to do with my `${"${file_type}_flag"}` but I don't know how to debug this. How can I print out the command that it tries to execute?

Don't mention that `${old_file}` or `${new_file}` don't exist. They are on the form `nameOfFile.h` or `nameOfFile.cpp` etc.

Comment: @ikegami: The OP says “How can I print out the command that it tries to execute” so it clearly *did* occur to them to do so

Comment: @Borodin, Indeed, oops.

Comment: There are some very major off-topic issues with the above code, starting with the dynamic generate of variable names.

Comment: I am puzzled about what you are showing us, and you seem to be confused about what is Perl code and what is shell. My first thought isn't about `$old_file` and `$new_file` but rather where `$ct`, `$old_view` and `$new_view` come from, and why you expect Perl to be able to see the contents of C++ source files. If you explain more about what you need to do and how you are running your program then I am sure we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It has obviously something to do with my `${"${file_type}_flag"}` but I don't know how to debug this. How can I print out the command that it tries to execute?

With `print`, of course.

```
print(qq{${loc} ${"${type}_flag"} ${old_view_path}/${old_file} > ${tmpdir}/old_file\n});
```

`warn` will send it to STDERR instead.

```
warn(qq{${loc} ${"${type}_flag"} ${old_view_path}/${old_file} > ${tmpdir}/old_file\n});
```